# Renaming a file using rename() function with counter in php

Tags: php, function

Hello gurus in the house. Please i want to rename a file using rename() function, but this will be if/while the file exist let it use counter to rename to another file.

example, if **sitemap.txt** exist let it rename it to **sitemap1.txt**
if **sitemap1.txt** exist let it rename it to **sitemap2.txt**, if **sitemap.txt**, **sitemap1.txt**, **sitemap2.txt** exist let it rename it to **sitemap3.txt** and so on.

```
$filename = 'sitemap.txt';
$FileCounter = 1;
while (file_exists( $filename )){
rename($filename, "sitemap". $FileCounter++ .".txt");
}
```

the above is the piece of code it works but each time sitemap1 exist, it refuses to move over to the next counter which is sitemap2.txt

I don't really how to make the counter work fine. but I need this only on `rename()` function.

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: try `rename($filename, "sitemap". $FileCounter .".txt"); $FileCounter++;`

Comment: You have to fetch all files from directory, then have to add condition in below while loop
    $dir = "/images/";
    
    // Open a directory, and read its contents
    if (is_dir($dir)){
      if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){
          //enter condition here
        }
        closedir($dh);
      }
    }

Comment: Do you mean that you want to increase the number on each file that starts with the name `sitemap`?

Comment: I want to rename the file sitemap.txt to the increasing order @Magnus

Comment: @suraj chand the sitemap file is on the root directory

Comment: You can easily flood your server with copies of copies of copies of the same file... What is your intention? Anyway. Your loop must find the filename that DOESNT exist, and it must remember the previous file... then you can copy the previous (existing, last) file to the (non-existing, new) filename.

Comment: My intentions are to copy same file because each time users searches on my site, it stores their search keyword there and I want to duplicate it once it get to specific limit of search text. Which I have already done. Just this line of code is what I am finding hard to get. @ Lars Stagelitz

Answer (score 0):

a solution could be to do the first rename, then loop until a file is reached, in order to rename it to the next counter:

```
    // if sitemap exists,
    if (file_exists("sitemap.txt")) {
        // rename it to sitemap1
        rename("sitemap.txt", "sitemap1.txt");
    }
    // if not, likely sitemaps1+ exist
    else {
        // init a new counter
        $FileCounter = 0;
        do {
            // increment the counter to check the next sitemap file
            $FileCounter++;
            // if sitemap<n> exists, break the loop
            $exist = file_exists("sitemap{$FileCounter}.txt");
        } while (!$exist);
        // prepare source and destination counters (n and n + 1)
        $NextFileCounter = $FileCounter + 1;
        // perform the rename
        rename("sitemap{$FileCounter}.txt", "sitemap{$NextFileCounter}.txt");
    }
```

this should work, let me know if current snippet is what you were looking for!

Comment: sorry but ur line if codes did nothing... i think the best way is to follow the snippet code i introduced on the question.

Comment: you have to create the first sitemap.txt file in order for this to work